# python response decode corrupted

Tags: python, web-scraping

i am new to python and data scraping.
i am trying to get data on some car models using python script.
the problem i ran into is python decoding response into text that is mixed up and does not match the response content.
found out that info i need is contained inside one of script tags inside html head element.
here is simplified script i am using:

```
import requests
import lxml.html
urls = "https://www.ultimatespecs.com/car-specs/Audi/119438/Audi-A3-(8Y)-Sedan-35-TDI.html"
res = requests.get(urls)
print(res.headers)
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(res.content)
helem = lxml.html.tostring(tree.xpath('//head/script[@type=\'application/ld+json\']')[0])
print(helem)
print(helem.decode('utf-8'))
```

response header

> {'Date': 'Sun, 14 Feb 2021 10:54:09 GMT', **'Content-Type': 'text/html;
> charset=UTF-8'**, 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection':
> 'keep-alive', 'Set-Cookie':
> '__cfduid=d938bb826c443ab15f20272199e2f18141613300048; expires=Tue,
> 16-Mar-21 10:54:08 GMT; path=/; domain=.ultimatespecs.com; HttpOnly;
> SameSite=Lax, PHPSESSID=ea60d27909207143c5ccd860e6fb3b76; path=/',
> 'Expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'Cache-Control':
> 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Vary':
> 'Accept-Encoding,User-Agent', 'CF-Cache-Status': 'DYNAMIC',
> 'cf-request-id': '0841c63a9c0000b61bda381000000001', 'Expect-CT':
> 'max-age=604800,
> report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
> 'Report-To':
> '{"group":"cf-nel","endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report?s=kB6vGZn5zLDoI%2FeQt9AF8174Aanh5La%2Bvh2beLKlCdnrHv5jbEIhC0h3FUVb56wTidKKSMFq1zuWhbakIydNto3EBXMZRt%2BwLD2FZgMsmHH53aJpanc%3D"}],"max_age":604800}',
> 'NEL': '{"max_age":604800,"report_to":"cf-nel"}', 'Server':
> 'cloudflare', 'CF-RAY': '62163fd76b76b61b-TLL', 'Content-Encoding':
> 'gzip'}

helem as bytes:

> b'\r\t\t{\r\t\t"@context":
> "http://schema.org/",\r\t\t"@type": "Car",\r\t\t"brand":
> "Audi",\r\t\t"manufacturer": "Audi",\r\t\t"name": "Audi A3 (8Y) Sedan
> 35 TDI","description":"35 TDI Specs:Power 150 PS (148 hp);
> Diesel;Average consumption:3.6 l/100km (65 MPG);Dimensions:
> Length:449.5 cm (176.97 inches); Width:181.6 cm (71.5
> inches);Height:142.5 cm (56.1 inches);Weight:1390 kg (3064 lbs);Model
> Years 2020,2021","productionDate": "2020","mainEntityOfPage":
> "https://www.ultimatespecs.com/car-specs/Audi/119438/Audi-A3-(8Y)-Sedan-35-TDI.html","image":
> {\r\t\t\t\t\t"@type": "ImageObject",\r\t\t\t\t\t"contentUrl":
> "https://www.ultimatespecs.com/wallpaper.php?id=7243"\r\t\t\t\t\t}\r\t\t\t\t\t,"height":
> {\r\t\t\t"@type": "QuantitativeValue",\r\t\t\t"unitCode":
> "CMT",\r\t\t\t"value": "142.5"\r\t\t\t},"width": {\r\t\t\t"@type":
> "QuantitativeValue",\r\t\t\t"unitCode": "CMT",\r\t\t\t"value":
> "181.6"\r\t\t\t},"weight": {\r\t\t\t"@type":
> "QuantitativeValue",\r\t\t\t"unitCode": "KGM",\r\t\t\t"value":
> "1390"\r\t\t\t},"accelerationTime": {\r\t\t\t"@type":
> "QuantitativeValue",\r\t\t\t"unitCode": "SEC",\r\t\t\t"value":
> "8.4"\r\t\t\t},"driveWheelConfiguration": {\r\t\t\t"@type":
> "DriveWheelConfigurationValue",\r\t\t\t"@id":
> "https://schema.org/FrontWheelDriveConfiguration"},"bodyType":
> "Sedan","cargoVolume": {\r\t\t\t"@type":
> "QuantitativeValue",\r\t\t\t"unitCode": "LTR","value":
> "425"},"emissionsCO2": "96","fuelCapacity": {\r\t\t\t"@type":
> "QuantitativeValue",\r\t\t\t"unitCode": "LTR", "value":
> "50"\r\t\t\t},"fuelConsumption": {\r\t\t\t"@type":
> "QuantitativeValue",\r\t\t\t"unitText": "L/100
> km",\r\t\t\t"valueReference": "Average",\r\t\t\t"value":
> "3.6"\r\t\t\t},"fuelEfficiency": {\r\t\t\t"@type":
> "QuantitativeValue",\r\t\t\t"unitText": "US
> MPG",\r\t\t\t"valueReference": "Average",\r\t\t\t"value":
> "65"\r\t\t\t},"fuelType": "Diesel","numberOfDoors":
> "4","vehicleSeatingCapacity": "5","numberOfForwardGears":
> "7","vehicleTransmission": "Dualclutch Automatic","wheelbase":
> {\r\t\t\t"@type": "QuantitativeValue",\r\t\t\t"unitCode": "CMT",
> "value": "263.6"\r\t\t\t},"speed": {\r\t\t\t"@type":
> "QuantitativeValue",\r\t\t\t"unitCode": "KMH", "value":
> "232"\r\t\t\t},"vehicleConfiguration": "35
> TDI","vehicleEngine":[\r\t\t{\r\t\t"@type":"EngineSpecification",\r\t\t"fuelType":"Diesel","engineDisplacement":
> {\r\t\t\t"@type": "QuantitativeValue",\r\t\t\t"unitCode":
> "CMQ",\r\t\t\t"value": "1968"\r\t\t\t},"torque": {\r\t\t\t"@type":
> "QuantitativeValue",\r\t\t\t"unitCode": "NU",\r\t\t\t"value":
> "360"},"enginePower": {\r\t\t\t"@type":
> "QuantitativeValue",\r\t\t\t"unitCode": "N12",\r\t\t\t"value":
> "150"}}]} '

helem as text:

> "value": "150"}}]} ,: {cement":
> {eEngine":[SeatingCapacity": "5","numberOfForwardGears":
> "7","vehicleTransmission": "Dualclutch Automatic","wheelbase":
> {(176.97 inches); Width:181.6 cm (71.5 inches);Height:142.5 cm (56.1
> inches);Weight:1390 kg (3064 lbs);Model Years
> 2020,2021","productionDate": "2020","mainEntityOfPage":
> "https://www.ultimatespecs.com/car-specs/Audi/119438/Audi-A3-(8Y)-Sedan-35-TDI.html","image":
> {

as you can see the decoded text overlaps multiple times over itself.
what am i doing wrong?

Comment: which part is overlapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are looking to fetch the following data.

[image]

**Code**

```
import requests
import lxml.html
import json
import pprint as pp
urls = "https://www.ultimatespecs.com/car-specs/Audi/119438/Audi-A3-(8Y)-Sedan-35-TDI.html"
res = requests.get(urls)
tree = lxml.html.fromstring(res.content)
helem = tree.xpath('//head/script[@type=\'application/ld+json\']')[0].text
data = json.loads(helem)
pp.pprint(data,)
```

**Output**

```
{'@context': 'http://schema.org/',
 '@type': 'Car',
 'accelerationTime': {'@type': 'QuantitativeValue',
                      'unitCode': 'SEC',
                      'value': '8.4'},
 'bodyType': 'Sedan',
 'brand': 'Audi',
 'cargoVolume': {'@type': 'QuantitativeValue',
                 'unitCode': 'LTR',
                 'value': '425'},
 'description': '35 TDI Specs:Power 150 PS (148 hp); Diesel;Average '
                'consumption:3.6 l/100km (65 MPG);Dimensions: Length:449.5 cm '
                '(176.97 inches); Width:181.6 cm (71.5 inches);Height:142.5 cm '
                '(56.1 inches);Weight:1390 kg (3064 lbs);Model Years 2020,2021',
 'driveWheelConfiguration': {'@id': 'https://schema.org/FrontWheelDriveConfiguration',
                             '@type': 'DriveWheelConfigurationValue'},
 'emissionsCO2': '96',
 'fuelCapacity': {'@type': 'QuantitativeValue',
                  'unitCode': 'LTR',
                  'value': '50'},
 'fuelConsumption': {'@type': 'QuantitativeValue',
                     'unitText': 'L/100 km',
                     'value': '3.6',
                     'valueReference': 'Average'},
 'fuelEfficiency': {'@type': 'QuantitativeValue',
                    'unitText': 'US MPG',
                    'value': '65',
                    'valueReference': 'Average'},
 'fuelType': 'Diesel',
 'height': {'@type': 'QuantitativeValue', 'unitCode': 'CMT', 'value': '142.5'},
 'image': {'@type': 'ImageObject',
           'contentUrl': 'https://www.ultimatespecs.com/wallpaper.php?id=7243'},
 'mainEntityOfPage': 'https://www.ultimatespecs.com/car-specs/Audi/119438/Audi-A3-(8Y)-Sedan-35-TDI.html',
 'manufacturer': 'Audi',
 'name': 'Audi A3 (8Y) Sedan 35 TDI',
 'numberOfDoors': '4',
 'numberOfForwardGears': '7',
 'productionDate': '2020',
 'speed': {'@type': 'QuantitativeValue', 'unitCode': 'KMH', 'value': '232'},
 'vehicleConfiguration': '35 TDI',
 'vehicleEngine': [{'@type': 'EngineSpecification',
                    'engineDisplacement': {'@type': 'QuantitativeValue',
                                           'unitCode': 'CMQ',
                                           'value': '1968'},
                    'enginePower': {'@type': 'QuantitativeValue',
                                    'unitCode': 'N12',
                                    'value': '150'},
                    'fuelType': 'Diesel',
                    'torque': {'@type': 'QuantitativeValue',
                               'unitCode': 'NU',
                               'value': '360'}}],
 'vehicleSeatingCapacity': '5',
 'vehicleTransmission': 'Dualclutch Automatic',
 'weight': {'@type': 'QuantitativeValue', 'unitCode': 'KGM', 'value': '1390'},
 'wheelbase': {'@type': 'QuantitativeValue',
               'unitCode': 'CMT',
               'value': '263.6'},
 'width': {'@type': 'QuantitativeValue', 'unitCode': 'CMT', 'value': '181.6'}}

Process finished with exit code 0
```